# Why are the second and the sixth pin of 555 timer named as they are?

Tags: integrated-circuit, oscillator

- Why is pin 2 of the 555 timer named trigger?
- Why is pin 6 of the 555 timer named threshold?

Comment: have you studied the 555 internal schematic diagram?

Comment: yes I have studied it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To **TRIGGER** the timer and send it's output to a high state you must take the **TRIGGER** pin (pin 2) below the **TRIGGER** level which is Vcc/3. Then to reset the timer's output to a low state you must take the **TRIGGER** pin above the Vcc/3 **TRIGGER** level but additionally you must then take the **THRESHOLD** pin (pin 6) above the **THRESHOLD** level of 2*Vcc/3.

So, as you should be able to see, the pins are named according to their circuit function.